# What Bash Statement does

Tags: bash

Can you explain to me what the below statement does.

```
grep `date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 day ago'` /path/to/file/FILE_PREFIX_\`date +%Y%m%d --date='1 day ago'`.dsv | grep -v 'ERROR' | cut -d "|" -f 2 | sed 's/^0/27/'
```

Comment: Why don't you try yourself and then let us know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have this file:

```
$ cat path/to/file/FILE_PREFIX_20150730.dsv
2015-07-29|0100
2015-07-30|0200
2015-07-30|0300
2015-07-31|0400
```

Now observe what your command (slightly fixed) does:

```
$ grep `date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 day ago'` path/to/file/FILE_PREFIX_`date +%Y%m%d --date='1 day ago'`.dsv  | grep -v 'ERROR' | cut -d "|" -f 2 | sed 's/^0/27/'
27200
27300
```

In short, it looks at a file whose name is based on yesterday's date, `path/to/file/FILE_PREFIX_20150730.dsv`.  It looks for any line in that file that mentions yesterday's date in the form `2015-07-30`.  It then eliminates any line which also contains the characters `ERROR`. The remaining lines are divided into fields based on the character `|`.  The second field of the line is extracted.  If that second field starts with a zero, then the zero is replaced with `27`.

Comment: It doen't necessarily do this. Try setting `$IFS` to a number - or, as is much more common - a dash.

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, that is one of many advanced options one could set to make the command misbehave or fail.

Comment: What do you consider *Advanced* about altering the value of a shell variable?

Answer (score 0):

For starters what you give is not a statement. It's a bunch of commands chained together through **Pipes** and **Command substitution**.

```
grep `date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 day ago'` /path/to/file/FILE_PREFIX_\`date +%Y%m%d --date='1 day ago'`.dsv | grep -v 'ERROR' | cut -d "|" -f 2 | sed 's/^0/27/'
```

Let's pick them apart one by one.

### Command Substitution

- `date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 day ago'` appears twice and gives you yesterday's date in format `YYYY-mm-dd` (e.g. 2015-07-31)

  - Second call (the one in the path name) adjusts the format to `YYYYmmdd`
  - Putting it into backticks makes it a **Command Substitution**. This is the same you would achieve by typing `$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 day ago')` only that the latter (and newer) form allows for nesting and is less cumbersome with regard to escaping.

The effect of **Command Substitution** in your command line is similar to assigning

```
YESTERDAY1=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 day ago')
YESTERDAY2=$(date +%Y%m%d --date='1 day ago')
```

and then rewriting the command line like this

```
grep $YESTERDAY1 /path/to/file/FILE_PREFIX_$YESTERDAY2.dsv | grep -v 'ERROR' | cut -d "|" -f 2 | sed 's/^0/27/'
```

### The individual parts chained by pipes

- `grep $YESTERDAY1 /path/to/file/FILE_PREFIX_$YESTERDAY2.dsv` greps for the value of yesterday's date in the file `/path/to/file/FILE_PREFIX_$YESTERDAY2.dsv` and outputs that to `stdout` (see [Standard Streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams))
- `grep -v 'ERROR'` greps for everything *other* than lines containing `ERROR`. It does that on the input from `stdin` and also writes to `stdout`.
- `cut -d "|" -f 2` assumes the input line (from `stdin`) is delimited by pipe characters (`-d "|"`, note how the pipe character is in a string here!) and picks the second field (`-f 2`) and writes that to `stdout`.
- `sed 's/^0/27/'` substitutes (`s/.../.../`) all strings from `stdin` (remember, second field from original input) starting (`^`) with 0 by 27 and writes them to `stdout`.

### Piping

Now the pipe characters that appear outside of a string, i.e. all but the single one in `cut -d "|" -f 2` chain the `stdout` of the preceding command to `stdin` of the following command.

This way the output of the first `grep` which reads the file, goes to the second `grep` which

This follows the Unix philosophy principle ["Do one thing and do it well"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well).

### Putting it all together

In my explanation I used the variable `YESTERDAY1` and `YESTERDAY2` introduced in the section on Command Substitution. Now you should be able to understand it.

One thing, though. I doubt it would come to that, but on a very sluggish system around midnight the time between running those two Command Substitutions may be big enough to yield different values for the file name and the value we `grep` for.

#### By the way

If you want to be really sophisticated and sidestep the issue that the value of yesterday could turn out different, you can use **Parameter Expansion** (`${parameter/pattern/string}`) like so. First get the date into a variable via **Command Substitution**:

```
YESTERDAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date='1 day ago')
```

and then use the **Parameter Expansion** to remove the dashes from once instance of the variable like this:

```
grep $YESTERDAY /path/to/file/FILE_PREFIX_${YESTERDAY//-}.dsv | grep -v 'ERROR' | cut -d "|" -f 2 | sed 's/^0/27/'
```

This way you only retrieve the date value once and avoid the (however slim) chance of getting different dates.

### Suggested reading

- Bash `man` page on your system or [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)
- The [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)